# Why is the mysqli query submitting twice to a database?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, increment

```
if (!$mysqli->query("UPDATE custom_fav SET credits = credits + 1 WHERE user_id = $current")) {
    echo "Credit addition failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
} else {
    echo 'hi';
}
```

Does anybody know why the mysqli query keeps running twice?

I am getting 1 of the echo statements but I am getting + 2 added to the database instead of 1.

For example i changed it to 5 and it added 10 into the database.

Comment: Please include some of the code above and below it.

Comment: Nothing in what you have here would cause the side-effect you describe. As the answer says, you must be calling this code twice somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you are calling this script twice. It this script called via home-brewed SEO-friendly URL? Do not make it act as a 404 handler then.

Comment: Ok I will check my chrome network tab to see if it is loading the page twice, and then I will post back.

Comment: Ok I have checked and yes the page is loading twice, but I have noticed that the page has to load twice for some other content to work which I have not created, is there a way that I can make it run once even with it loading the page again via jquery.

Comment: I am going to place my script into another file and use ajax to run the script when their is user input so then it can't run twice.

Comment: Too bad I just realized it after few hours of hard debugging.

Comment: @AdamLesniak it gave you a precious thing in exchange - practical experience. Learning on your own trial and error is incomparable to just reading of others'. There are too much people around here, who have no real knowledge but just repeat one after another without real understanding of the things. So, I'd rather praise these hours than blame :)